# Doubt about conservative fields in 2D and 3D

Tags: calculus, integration, vector-fields, line-integrals

Regarding a conservative field $\vec{F}$ in a region $D \subseteq R^2$, I know that the requirements are:

1. Curl of $\vec{F}$ is $0$.
2. $\vec{F}$ is defined in D (doesn't have singularities in D).

But I have doubts about the conditions that must be met for a vector field to be considered conservative in $R^3$, as I have understood (by the comments of teachers or test solutions I've seen), it is not necessary to show that a vector field is defined in a region $D$ to consider it as conservative in D, it seems that that is enough if the curl is 0, but I never managed to understand it (if it really is like that), why is that so?

Comment: I don't think it would matter as long as you do not go over the singularity. For example the electric field of a point charge contains singularity, yet it is still a conservative field.

Comment: @grdgfgr If that is the case, what is the difference between the radial fields $-r^{-2}e_r$ in two and three dimensions? In a plane through $(0,0,0)$, both are the same, and both have a singularity at zero. Therefore any line integrals with paths in such a plane should behave in the same way, right?

Comment: @Chappers: Radial fields where the strength depends only on the distance to the center are always conservative (no matter what that dependency is), so that is not a really good example.

Comment: @Chappers wouldn't a radial field in two dimensions be $r^{-1}e_r$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct condition is that the field to be defined *on a simply connected subset* of $\mathbb R^n$ before a local condition is enough to be sure it is conservative.

For example, consider the following field defined on $\mathbb R^3$ except for the $z$-axis:
$$ \vec F(x,y,z) = \frac1{x^2+y^2}(-y,x,0) $$
This is not conservative -- if you go around the unit circle in the $xy$-plane you either win or lose $2\pi$ energy, depending on the direction. But the curl is $0$ everywhere the field is defined.